# How to extract voltage and current from this real-life circuit (with resistors)

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, voltage-measurement

I recently measured some voltages across two resistors as you can see in the images below.

I used a triangle wave as voltage source and measured the voltages across the resistors with an oscilloscope.

The top one is the theoretical circuit and below the one I built as an experiment.

[image]

[image]

How do I get the proper voltage across and current flowing through my measuring resistor RM that is about 1 MΩ in the experiment?

In theory CH1 shows the voltage across RM and by measuring the voltage across my testing resistor RT on CH2 I can get the current via I = U/RT. Is this correct?

But when calculating the resistance of RM via RM = U/I, I don't get the indicated value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, take note of the oscilloscope's input impedance. It will be important later.

[image]

*Figure 1. The 'scope's input impedance is 1 MΩ.*

Now let's look at your circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyTW5S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. The equivalent circuit showing loading by the oscilloscope probes.*

The CH2 input won't cause any loading because the output impedance of the signal generator is very low in comparison and, as a result, the voltage won't be pulled down.

The CH1 input is in parallel with RM and since they are both 1 MΩ the effective resistance at that point in the circuit is 500 kΩ. Therefore you can expect the 'scope CH1 to read a little less than half of the CH2 reading.

---

We can make analysis a little easier by using a 1 V DC source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhK65G.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Voltage measurement with a 1 GΩ voltmeter.*

Note the voltmeters have negligible effect on the circuit so the voltages measured are those that would exist if the meters were removed. Note that the voltage at the junction of the resistors is about 2/3 of the supply, as expected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsHvam.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. Voltage measurement with oscilloscope connected.*

Here we can see that CH2 doesn't load the voltage source. It's reading 1 V.

Meanwhile the resistance at the lower part of the resistor divider has been halved by the addition of the 1 MΩ scope input in parallel with RM. Now we've got 510 kΩ on top and 500 kΩ on the bottom so the voltmeter reads a little less than half of the supply voltage.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your insights. Just as you described I‘m getting the resistance of RT instead of RM. May you again explain in terms of current flow why this is the case?  As I understand there is no current going through channel 2, but back to the function generator because the impedance of the oscilloscope is too high.

Comment: @Leon, see the update. I've shown the voltages so you should be able to work out the currents.

Comment: @Leon You could improve your testing and have measurements closer to theoretical if you were to use a scope with a higher input resistance. There may even be 10x scope probes available that would increase the input resistance and reduce measurement error. Alternately in this case if the circuit is only for a learning example you could reduce the resistor values in the circuit by 10x or even 100x. More often to measure current in a circuit using an extra resistor you want that resistor to be a very small value. A small value resistor would introduce a smaller error in the other measurements.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the hints guys!

Comment: Thanks to your help, I'm able to calculate the resistance RM from the voltages I measured on CH1 and CH2. Just one dull question: I can't get the current through RM from my measurement, right?

Comment: Why not? You know the current through RT, you know the voltage across RM and CH1 so you can work out how much of the current is going through CH1 and the rest must be going through RM.

Comment: Do I really know how much current goes through RT ? Isn't it determined by the input current of the function generator IF ? If I were to know this value, then the current IT that passes through RT might be IT = IF - I2 where I2 = U2/1MΩ is the current through channel 2. Hence the current IM that passes through RM would be IM = IT - I1 where I1 = U1/1MΩ. But how do I get IF ? Dividing the voltage U2 on CH2 by the impedance RF of the function generator (50Ω) doesn't give a useful result when calculating RM = U1/IM.

Comment: $$ I_F = \frac {V_{CH2} - V_{CH1}} {R_T} $$

Answer (score 2):

That's because CH2 does not measure voltage over RT, so no, that is not correct.

The scope is not connected like the two meters in the schematic diagram.